# How do I get the hero and purifier bonuses when capturing shadow Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

This morning, I encountered my first Team Rocket grunt at a black pokéstop. Upon spinning the spot, I became engaged in a battle with the grunt and battled their shadow Pokémon. After I defeated them, it came to a post-battle screen similar to a raid battle that displayed the number of premiere balls I received.

There were two bonus categories where I received 0 on - Hero and Purifier. How do I obtain these bonuses?

[image: Grunt battle summary]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two bonuses correspond to two new badges of the same names added to the game:

**Hero** – Defeat 10 / 100 / 1000 Team GO Rocket Grunts

**Purifier** – Purify 5 / 50 / 500 Shadow Pokemon

Having these badges will grant you the bonus balls, with additional levels in the badge gaining additional extra balls.

([Source](https://piunikaweb.com/2019/07/23/pokemon-go-team-go-rocket-invasion-details-analysis-purified-pokemon-benefits/) for the badge levels; [Source](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokemon-go-team-rocket-invasions-begin-now) for the bonuses.)